# This should be real easy. How to find a button through its Value (Jquery Selector)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this HTML:

```
<div id='grid'>
<input type="button" value="edit"/>
<input type='button' value='update'/>
</div>
```

How to I attach a click event only to Update button. I know I could add a class to it or specity an id but both are not possible since it is in gridview.

I tried this:

```
$("input:button[@value='update']").click(function(){alert('test');});
```

but it displays an alert for both buttons. I know I must be doing something silly. Any help is much appreciated.

**Thanks Kobi & Sarfraz for helping me out. Given below is the right answer.**

```
$("input[value='update']").click(function(){alert('test');});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[value='update']").click(function(){alert('test');});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Now it is not displaying an alert for both. http://jsfiddle.net/aX5wf/

Answer (score 2):

As per [the documentation for Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), in jQuery you should not have an `@` when referring to attributes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS selectors, and to select that, you should not use `@` in CSS.